# Replace specific text in a file with each line of a list in another file

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a txt file, which is a huge list. Each line represents a value.

I'd like to replace each specific value in the main file with each line of the txt file.

Searched, but couldn't find something similar in bash or python.

Example (every "1" in the main file should be replaced with each line of the txt file):

```
Txt file
A
B
C
D
E

Main file
httpDownload("1", localPath .."1")
httpDownload("1", localPath .."1")
httpDownload("1", localPath .."1")
httpDownload("1", localPath .."1")
httpDownload("1", localPath .."1")

Result
httpDownload("A", localPath .."A")
httpDownload("B", localPath .."B")
httpDownload("C", localPath .."C")
httpDownload("D", localPath .."D")
httpDownload("E", localPath .."E")
```

Comment: unclear. did you post the actual `main` file contents?

Comment: Main file would contain "1" repeated times. Every "1" in the main file should be replaced with one line for the txt file.

Comment: what if main file contains more lines than txt file?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: It wouldn't contain more lines. I have a script (main file) with repeated commands. The amount of commands matches the amount of lines in the txt file. I need to replace a specific information on each command with a line of the txt file. Every line for every command.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Updated the question with result example.

Comment: In the `Main file` is the number of lines the same as the number of lines in the `txt file`? Ie. can you just `paste` the files together? Then `paste` the files together, then use `sed` with backreference to do the substitution.

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same.

Comment: Both solutions suggested so far will fail silently and cryptically given some non-alphanumeric values in the text file (e.g. `&`). Is that acceptable? If your input is **always** just alphanumeric it'll be fine, otherwise I wouldn't use a gsub() approach (at least not without additional protections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {gsub(/1/,a[++count])} 1' text_file main_file
```

***OR*** To save output into main_file itself use following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {gsub(/1/,a[++count])} 1' text_file main_file > temp && mv temp main_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
httpDownload("A", localPath .."A")
httpDownload("B", localPath .."B")
httpDownload("C", localPath .."C")
httpDownload("D", localPath .."D")
httpDownload("E", localPath .."E")
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case your text_file is having lesser string values than your main_file then you may need to start it from 1st(from A character again to place it in main_file) then use following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$0
  next
}
FNR==1{
  val=length(a)
}
{ 
  gsub(/1/,a[++count])
  count=val==count?0:count
}
1
' text_file main_file
```

Comment: Apparently it worked. However, didn't save the file (just showed output in the terminal).

Comment: @AndréLuís, Check it now, you can use my 1st solution's OR option and let me know then?

Comment: It's giving me blank output. It worked once, but it's no longer working. Lemme see if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Yup. I was doing something wrong (main file was empty). It works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréLuís, It worked fine for me, lemme know in case of any queries here.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `gawk`'s **[`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Plain-Getline.html#Plain-Getline)** feature to consume a line from specified file:

```
$ awk '{ getline c < "f1.txt"; gsub("1", c, $0) }1' main.txt
httpDownload("A", localPath .."A")
httpDownload("B", localPath .."B")
httpDownload("C", localPath .."C")
httpDownload("D", localPath .."D")
httpDownload("E", localPath .."E")
```

Answer (score 0):

Robustly:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    tgt  = 1
}
NR==FNR {
    if ( /"/ ) {
        printf "WARNING: %s line %d contains \": %s\n", FILENAME, NR, $0 | "cat>&2"
    }
    if ( /\\$/ ) {
        printf "WARNING: %s line %d ends in \\: %s\n", FILENAME, NR, $0 | "cat>&2"
    }
    vals[NR] = $0
    next
}
{
    old = $0
    new = ""
    while ( pos = index(old,tgt) ) {
        new = new substr(old,1,pos-1) vals[FNR]
        old = substr(old,pos+length(tgt))
    }
    $0 = new old
    print
}
```

.

```
$ cat file
"
&
\
\1
E

$ awk -f tst.awk file main
httpDownload(""", localPath ..""")
httpDownload("&", localPath .."&")
httpDownload("\", localPath .."\")
httpDownload("\1", localPath .."\1")
httpDownload("E", localPath .."E")
WARNING: file line 1 contains ": "
WARNING: file line 3 ends in \: \
```